# Access denied for user ' ' (using password: YES)Connection Failed : Access denied for user ' ' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

am getting this error

```
Access denied for user ''@'' (using password: YES)
Connection Failed : Access denied for user ''@'' (using password: YES)
```

```php
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$number = $_POST['number'];

// Database connection
$conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1:3306 ','u380872581_tembemoriz','198617940mM*','u380872581_Project');
if($conn->connect_error){
    echo "$conn->connect_error";
    die("Connection Failed : ". $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into registration(firstName, lastName, gender, email, password, number) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssi", $firstName, $lastName, $gender, $email, $password, $number);
    $execval = $stmt->execute();
    echo $execval;
    echo "Registration successfully...";
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
}
```

Comment: link to site project.tembemoriz.com

Comment: Can you please try to remove spaces from '127.0.0.1:3306 ' ?

Comment: and also try to use localhost instead of ip may be that will work. the error saying is that connection has problem with mysql.